# How to Cover Linq Statements from unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, moq, rhino-mocks, unity-test-framework

I have `UpdateEmployees()` method which updates all employees data.

While writing Unit test for that method, it is not covering `OrderBy()` statement. How can I get code coverage for order by statement.

I have used Moq unit test.

```c#
//This Method returns list of employee
Public void UpdateEmployees()
{
     var employees = _repository.GetAllEmployees().OrderBy(x => x.Name);
     // Some Update operations below.
}

//Unit Test for GetAllEmployee Method.
Public void UnitTest()
{
    var employees = new Fixture.Build<Employee>().Createmany(5).ToList();
    var moqRepository = new Mock<IRepository>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    moqRepository.Setup(r => r.GetAllEmployees()).Returns(employees)

    var employee = new Employee(moqRepositort.Object);
    employee.UpdateEmployees();
}
```

Comment: Try `result.SequenceEqual(employees.OrderBy(e => e.Name));`

Comment: @artm - apology I modified method. My method has no return type. It is void method.

Comment: What do you mean, how to get code coverage? If your method uses the contents of `employees` and there are at least two elements, the OrderBy clause will always be executed. How do you know this code isn't covered?

Comment: In any case, if you want to test the behavior of `OrderBy` you should create a separate test, not depend on some other test executing this line

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos . My method returns 5 employees but still it is not covering that order by part. Is it anything to do with setup?

Comment: `//Some update operations` Then does it matter that they are ordered? If you're updating them all regardless of order then you don't need to order them or test that they are ordered. If updating logic depends on them to be in Name order, then you can check your update result in your test.

Answer (score 1):

OrderBy would get covered if it's enumerated to List:

```
var employees = _repository.GetAllEmployees().OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```